# Overlapping patterns regex

Tags: python, regex

with python and regex I attempt to match repeating/overlapping patterns/blocks like

```
04/00127-48
U 05062012
A: SAKARK
T_ Par.: dsfsd
```

in

```
04/00127-48
U 05062012
A: SAKARK
T_ Par.: dsfsd
04/00168-42
U 05062012
A: SAKARK
T_ Par.: fdfs
04/00168-43
U 05062012
A: SAKARK
T_ Par.: fdfs
```

I have tried

```
'(?=(\d+\/.*))'
```

this seem to work

```
'((\d+\/.*?)=?\d+\/)
```

but is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm confused, which patterns are you trying to extract? What is your intended result?

Comment: sorry about the bad question, I want to match the text blocks

Comment: See Marco de Wit's answer. Notice his usage of the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers your question:

```
re.findall(r'.+?(?=\d\d\/|$)',s,re.DOTALL)
```

`re.DOTALL` is needed to let the `.` match end-of-lines.

The `r` in front of the regex makes it a raw string so escapes with backslash are left as they are so the regex function will handle them. It is not needed here but still a good habit for regex's.

Your question is not very clear. Maybe this matches better what you want?

```
list(zip(*[iter(s.splitlines())]*4))
```

It gives a list with tuples.